# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController to tabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am trying to pass the data from one tabBarController to second tabBarController but I am getting error , I tried many methods but data is not passing

is their anyway to pass the data between tabs?

I am trying with this code but I am getting error " Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController to CategoriesViewController"

```
enter code here



    let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers

    let svc = barViewControllers![1] as! CategoriesViewController 

    svc.categoriesData = self.categoryProductsDict  //shared model
```

Comment: think this way : tab bar -> navigation controller -> your controller. So you got navigation controller, you need to loop to get your controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let svc = (barViewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0]
```

I believe all the tab viewControllers have embedded navigation controller. So when you access viewController from tabs viewController you get UINavigationController. In order to access VC you have to get the viewControllers at index 0 of NavigationController

Much cleaner safer code

```
if let vc = (self.tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as? CategoriesViewController {
   //access your VC here                            
}
```